# Need to grab address column and pass it to an array

Tags: javascript, list-view, column

My script uses an array like this:

```
var locations = [
    ['Location 1 Name', 'New York, NY', 'Location 1 URL'],
    ['Location 2 Name', 'Newark, NJ', 'Location 2 URL'],
    ['Location 3 Name', 'Philadelphia, PA', 'Location 3 URL'],
];
```

I have a page with two list webparts (A and B). webpart A/List A has two columns

Title and Address

Using javascript, i need to be able to grab the data from Address column and pass that to my array.

I've tried ANYTHING javscript related for sharepoint, but nothing seems to run.

i have script.js in my SiteAssets folder and in a CONTENT EDITOR webpart i added the call for the script  `<script src=pathToMyScript> </script>`

I tried running a alert("hello"); to confirm that its working and the alert works fine, but as soon as i add javascript that i've seen anywhere in this page or other pages, nothing seems to be working as nothing shows or loads.

Things to note: Treat me as if i knew nothing about javascript and sharepoint. However, i do know how to program in javascript. I never used sp.js libraries.

Comment: (IMHO) the best way to learn programming *against* SharePoint is to use the Chrome Browser and start with Chrome Snippets, that way you pass all the loading SharePoint libraries and focus on what you want to get done first. After you succeeded there you make the step to load it in a SharePoint page. It is a reversal of typical development in blogs.. But those Chrome Snippets are a a very powerful way of quickly getting results and not getting disparaged by SharePoint code. It is also easier to post code with your StackOverflow questions then

Comment: Yup, i tried that too, but does sharepoint load sp.js and all the requried libraries automatically or do i have to reference to them manually? for some reason, when i run the snippets nothing happens.. i saw somewhere a code where the script is supposed to grab the data from a list then alert(list) but i get [Object Object]. I copied and pasted http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178060/convert-list-data-to-excel-and-upload-it-to-document-library-without-downloading (see moryas answer) and it didnt do anything. no excel sheet was created

Comment: Check the Network tab on what is loaded. sp.js is so generic it is loaded on almost all pages. Since you are coding from a Chrome Snippet your code always executes after all resources have loaded. So if you get errors now, it is your code, not a missing sp.js. If you need stuff like userprofiles etc. you will get syntax or undefined errors in the Console and you know something is missing.

Comment: Oh, and try to avoid ``alert`` That is 1996 script kiddie coding... Learn to use ``console.log( )`` (warning: don't leave console statements in the final code, as Internet Explorer only allows use when the F12 console is opened, so when your user says it doesn't work, your test with the Console openened will work... I burn myself on this one in every project still

Comment: Running this on a snipper gets me undefined

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, but i do not know what it is. anything i try to run for sharepoint gets me undefined, this is getting fustrating. I'll just tell my client it cant be done lol.

Comment: Post the snippet you tried, then people can help

Comment: Here is the code i'm trying to use, forget about the snippets, they do not work as i expected them to work. So this http://pastebin.com/FYwbh3n1

Comment: Line 54 is out of order. Learn to program with Google Maps first before you try to implement it in SharePoint.. You are trying to run before you can walk.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to question at below link, putting answer here as below is marked as duplicate.
[Passing List Items to Array](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204664/passing-list-items-to-array)

If I understood correctly, you  need 2D javascript array...I have not tested below but to give you idea, it should work.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var locations = new Array(collListItem.get_count());
    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        eventName = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        eventAddress = oListItem.get_item('WorkAddress');
        eventURL = website.get_url() + '/' + 'Lists/North East Reports/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id();
        var newLocation = [eventName, eventAddress, eventURL];
        locations.push(newLocation);

         listItemInfo += 
               //'\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
               '\nEvent Name: ' +  eventName +//oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nAddress: ' + eventAddress +//oListItem.get_item('WorkAddress') +
            '\nURL: ' + eventURL;//website.get_url() + '/' + 'Lists/North East Reports/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id(); 
    }

    //alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
```

Comment: Seems to be going the right path, but marker pins are still not generated.. see previous answer comment for complete code, i added your changes to my script, but yet no pins are being generated on the map. It's almost as if the array is not getting to the second part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create locations array and then push location with properties. like this.

```
// Create Array 
var locations = [];
// Push items into array
locations.push(eventName, eventAddress, eventURL);
```

Here is complete code.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
var locations = [];
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        eventName = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        eventAddress = oListItem.get_item('WorkAddress');
        eventURL = website.get_url() + '/' + 'Lists/North East Reports/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id();

        locations.push(eventName, eventAddress, eventURL);
        listItemInfo += 
               //'\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
               '\nEvent Name: ' +  eventName +//oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nAddress: ' + eventAddress +//oListItem.get_item('WorkAddress') +
            '\nURL: ' + eventURL;//website.get_url() + '/' + 'Lists/North East Reports/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id(); 
    }
//alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
```

Comment: Didn't Work http://pastebin.com/FYwbh3n1 This is my full code

Comment: Updated the script, still not working.. i dont know what to check anymore..